# Python Telegram Bot - How to send JSON response.content as PDF file

Tags: python-telegram-bot

With the conversational Bot, I need to hit a URL which returns a PDF file in response.content JSON. I want to send this file directly to the User without saving it on the server. How can this be done?
Sample Code:

```
response = requests.get(url)  
pdf = open("pdffile.pdf", 'wb')  
pdf.write(response.content)  
pdf.close()  
file = "pdffile.pdf"
update.message.reply_document(document=open(file, 'rb'))
```

I don't want to perfrom the **write** operation

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly do you mean with "the conversational Bot"? Does the URL link directly to the file? Are you actually using the `pyhon-telegram-bot` library (asking this b/c this label is often misused)? Please also have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: @CallMeStag yes, i'm using pyhon-telegram-bot.. I make a POST call and the response is a PDF file. I want to directly send this file to the user

Comment: Then you might have a chance to pass the bytes stream directly as `send_document(document=bytes_stream)`, but this is somewhat hard to say without some code example or more info about how exactly you fetch the PDF.

Comment: here's the sample  

Sample code
`response = requests.get(url)  
pdf = open("pdffile.pdf", 'wb')  
pdf.write(response.content)  
pdf.close()  
file = 'pdffile.pdf '
update.message.reply_document(document=open(file, 'rb'))`  

I don't want to perfrom the `write` operation  
 @CallMeStag sorry am not able to indent the code properly..

Comment: couldn't format the code in the comments thus added in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in my comments above, you can pass a bytes stream to `send_document`. Here is minimal example based on your code snippet (plug in your bot token and your chat id):

```
import requests
from telegram import Bot

bot = Bot("TOKEN")
response = requests.get('https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/')
bot.send_document(YOUR_CHAT_ID, document=response.content, filename='python-telegram-bot.pdf')
```

Note that I passed the `filename` parameter. This allows you to give a custom filename that will be displayed for the recipient.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thanks a ton @CallMeStag .. it worked :) Sorry for the late reply, was busy through the week and just tried your solution. Perfect.